# remove all the subview on cell.contentview except the label

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiview

If we use the following code I can remove all the subviews including the textLabel. I need to remove all except the contentview titlelabel

```
for (int i=0; i < [self.mylist count]; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *lIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lIndexPath];

    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

any idea how to avoid that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check whether the view is of type UILabel, thats it

```
for (int i=0; i < [self.mylist count]; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *lIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lIndexPath];



    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if(![view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        else
        {
        //check if it titlelabel or not, if not remove it
        }
}
}
```

Comment: And what about if the removed label has constraints attached? For example I want to remove the middle label, but the one beneath it has a vertical constraint to the removed. Then the 2nd label wont fill the space of the removed label. How to fix that?